# Quote Items are showing only if flush cache - Magento 2

Tags: cart, magento2.3, cache, addtocart, quote

I am trying to get cart quote items by the following code:

**File**: app/code/Essence/Fcf/view/frontend/templates/packages.phtml

I called this file in my cms page by following code:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Essence_Fcf::packages.phtml" cacheable="false"}}
```

**packages.phtml**

```
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();      
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
}
echo $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
echo $cart->getQuote()->getItemsQty();
```

I am getting this value only if I flush cache after add to cart. I want this value without flushing cache direclty. How it is possible?

Comment: where you have tried? Block/Template phtml file?

Comment: See my updated question